# Any way I can speed up this sub procedure?

Tags: excel, vba

I figure there must be a way to drastically shorten this sub procedure. The reason why I even want to is because it's freezing up the application on the `elseif userform1.optTerm` line because that worksheet it pulls the data from is 6x longer in rows than the `optInSeat` list.

```
Sub LoadEmployee_Cmb_HC()
    Dim isWS As Worksheet: Set isWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("In Seat")
    Dim tWs As Worksheet: Set tWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Terms")
    Dim a, b As Long, c As Variant, i As Long
    If UserForm1.optInSeat = True Then
        If UserForm1.optEmployeeName = True Then
            For i = 2 To isWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row
                x = Application.CountIf(isWS.Range("D" & 4, "D" & i), _
                isWS.Cells(i, 4).Value)
                If x = 1 Then
                    UserForm1.cmbEmployee.AddItem isWS.Cells(i, 4) & " - " & isWS.Cells(i, 1)
                End If
            Next i
            For a = 0 To UserForm1.cmbEmployee.ListCount - 1
                For b = 0 To UserForm1.cmbEmployee.ListCount - 1
                    If UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b) > UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a) Then
                        c = UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a)
                        UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a) = UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b)
                        UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b) = c
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            ElseIf UserForm1.optEmployeeID = True Then
            For i = 2 To isWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
                x = Application.CountIf(isWS.Range("A" & 1, "A" & i), _
                isWS.Cells(i, 1).Value)
                If x = 1 Then
                    UserForm1.cmbEmployee.AddItem isWS.Cells(i, 1) & " - " & isWS.Cells(i, 4)
                End If
            Next i
            For a = 0 To UserForm1.cmbEmployee.ListCount - 1
                For b = 0 To UserForm1.cmbEmployee.ListCount - 1
                    If UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b) > UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a) Then
                        c = UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a)
                        UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a) = UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b)
                        UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b) = c
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    ElseIf UserForm1.optTerm = True Then
        If UserForm1.optEmployeeName = True Then
            For i = 2 To tWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row
                x = Application.CountIf(tWs.Range("D" & 4, "D" & i), _
                tWs.Cells(i, 4).Value)
                If x = 1 Then
                    UserForm1.cmbEmployee.AddItem tWs.Cells(i, 4) & " - " & tWs.Cells(i, 1)
                End If
            Next i
            For a = 0 To UserForm1.cmbEmployee.ListCount - 1
                For b = 0 To UserForm1.cmbEmployee.ListCount - 1
                    If UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b) > UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a) Then
                        c = UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a)
                        UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a) = UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b)
                        UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b) = c
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        ElseIf UserForm1.optEmployeeID = True Then
            For i = 2 To tWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
                x = Application.CountIf(tWs.Range("A" & 1, "A" & i), _
                tWs.Cells(i, 1).Value)
                If x = 1 Then
                    UserForm1.cmbEmployee.AddItem tWs.Cells(i, 1) & " - " & tWs.Cells(i, 4)
                End If
            Next i
            For a = 0 To UserForm1.cmbEmployee.ListCount - 1
                For b = 0 To UserForm1.cmbEmployee.ListCount - 1
                    If UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b) > UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a) Then
                        c = UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a)
                        UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(a) = UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b)
                        UserForm1.cmbEmployee.List(b) = c
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: bulk load variant arrays and loop them instead of the ranges themselves.

Comment: @ScottCraner kind of lost on what you mean. do you mean load the column values into an array and then do the `.additem` after that?

Comment: 1. Could you provide some sample data from the two worksheets? Copy the data in Excel, go to https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables, paste the data; then click **Generate**. Then, press **Copy to clipboard** and edit the table into your question. 2. For simplicity, the reordering of values within `cmbEmployees` after possibly adding one or more entries should be in a separate `Sub`; the `Sub` should take a `Boolean` specifying whether entries were added, and thus the code in the `Sub` needs to be run. 3. I don't have experience in UserForms, but it seems to me that instead of ...

Comment: ... iterating over each row in the relevant worksheet, testing it, then adding to the `cmbEmployees` if it matches the test; better produce a single array and push the entire array at once as the items in `cmbEmployees`. As an extension of this, I would suggest using ADO to connect to the relevant worksheet's data, filtering only the right data, and pushing the results into `cmbEmployees`; because recordsets have built-in sorting, you will save that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select unique items using a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) and sort them in an array. This sorts in ascending order.

```vb
Sub LoadEmployee_Cmb_HC()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict, k As String, i As Long
    Dim order(2) As Integer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' data source
    If UserForm1.optInSeat = True Then
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("In Seat")
    ElseIf UserForm1.optTerm = True Then
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Terms")
    End If

    ' sort by columns
    If UserForm1.optEmployeeName = True Then
        order(1) = 4: order(2) = 1
    ElseIf UserForm1.optEmployeeID = True Then
        order(1) = 1: order(2) = 4
    End If

    If order(1) = 0 Or ws Is Nothing Then
        ' do nothing
    Else
        ' get unique values start in row 4
        For i = 4 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, order(1)).End(xlUp).Row
            k = Trim(ws.Cells(i, order(1)).Value)
            If Len(k) > 0 And Not dict.exists(k) Then
                dict.Add k, k & " - " & Trim(ws.Cells(i, order(2)))
            End If
        Next
        ' sort and populate combo
        Call SortCombo(dict, UserForm1.ComboBox1)
    End If

End Sub

Sub SortCombo(ByRef dict, cmb As ComboBox)
    Dim ar, a As Long, b As Long, i As Long, tmp As String
    ar = dict.keys
    i = UBound(ar)
    For a = 0 To i
        For b = a To i
            If ar(b) < ar(a) Then
                tmp = ar(a)
                ar(a) = ar(b)
                ar(b) = tmp
            End If
        Next
        ar(a) = dict.Item(ar(a)) ' replace with value after it sort
    Next
    cmb.List = ar
End Sub
```

Alternative sort using temporary sheet

```vb
Sub SortCombo2(ByRef dict, cmb As ComboBox)
    
    Dim wsTmp As Worksheet, rng As Range, k, ar() As String, i As Long
    Set wsTmp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
    wsTmp.Cells.Clear
    ReDim ar(dict.Count - 1, 0)
    
    i = 0
    For Each k In dict.keys
       ar(i, 0) = dict(k)
       i = i + 1
    Next
    Set rng = wsTmp.Range("A1:A" & dict.Count)
    rng = ar

    With wsTmp.Sort
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
    cmb.List = rng.Value2
    wsTmp.Cells.Clear

End Sub
```

Test data generator

```vb
Sub data()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i, s, n
    Set ws = Sheets("Terms")
    ws.Cells.Clear

    For i = 4 To 35000
       s = ""
       For n = 1 To 25
          s = s & Chr(65 + Int(Rnd() * 26))
       Next
       ws.Cells(i, 1) = s
       ws.Cells(i, 4) = "D" & i
    Next
    MsgBox "done " & i - 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, appreciate the help! It works well until I click on the optTerms button (which has like 35k rows). getting a `Overflow run-time error 6` error on this line: `For i = 4 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, order(1)).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @nidenk change dim for I to long

Comment: still crashing excel with the `optTerms` piece, wonder why. It works great, just think it's sorting too big of a list of values (35k rows)

Comment: @nidenk How many of the 35k rows are items in the combobox ?

Comment: two columns worth

Comment: @NidenK The bubble sort is very inefficient O(n2). On my machine 5K took 5s, 10k was 12s, 15k was 49s. etc. So I have provided an alternative using a temporary sheet (sheet(3)) and excel sort which is much faster. The sheet could be hidden.

Comment: So this is working, but the '.sort' part is not, any idea why? I see that the temp ws is loading the values, which are then loading to the combobox, but no sort is being applied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229783/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-nidenk).

Comment: Could you take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66591182/111794) and see if I've got the logic right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to shape the data using code, I would suggest creating an SQL statement based on runtime logic, opening a recordset with that data, and pushing the result back into the combobox.

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects**; the latest version, usually `6.1`.

(Credit goes to [CDP1802's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66565919/111794), which is the basis for much of the logic here.)

```vb
Dim source As String
If optInSeat = True Then
    source = "'In Seat$'"
ElseIf optTerm = True Then
    source = "Terms$"
End If
If Len(source) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' Do nothing

' sort by columns
Dim orderBy As String, expr As String
If optEmployeeName Then
    expr = "Trim(F1) & ' - ' & Trim(F4)"
    orderBy = "F1, F4"
ElseIf optEmployeeID Then
    expr = "Trim(F4) & ' - ' & Trim(F1)"
    orderBy = "F4, F1"
Else
    expr = "Trim(F1) & ' - ' & Trim(F4)"
End If

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""

Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT " & expr & " " & _
    "FROM [" & source & "]"
If Len(orderBy) > 0 Then sql = sql & " ORDER BY " & orderBy

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString

' The 2D array comes back in the wrong direction to be set directly.
' We use WorksheetFunctions.Transpose to switch the direction.
cmbEmployees.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
```

Comment: Logic looks good, might need a space before ORDER. Not sure why the original question had the COUNTIF statements , I thought it was to select unique values like DISTINCT maybe.